# Proving $f$ is Riemann integrable without Lebesgue-Riemann criterion.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have been studying this criterion that tell us that if $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and almost everywhere continuous respect to $\lambda$ (the Lebesgue measure) iff $f$ is Riemann integrable.

My problem is that I had this example let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
0& x\in [0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}\\
1/q &\text{ if }p/q \text{ is the lowest expresion for }x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]
\end{array}\right.$$

So I know this functions is almost everywhere continuous and  bounded. So by the criterion is Riemann integrable.

But I wanted to prove that this Riemann integrable with out the criterion, as my intuition tells me that it shouldn't be Riemann integrable but the theorem say it is.

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of a uniform convergent series of functions?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, yes this answers my question Thank you,

Comment: @gba yes I'm familiar with the uniform convergent series of functions

Comment: There is a nice solution using the fact that if $f_n$ uniformly converges to $f$ and each $f_n$ is integrable, then $f$ is integrable.

Comment: @gba that sound really nice, do you know where I can find it?

Comment: I'll post it a little later - at least some main ideas in the proof and I'll let you fill the rest